# How to draw a circle instead of an ellipse when your monitor screen resolution isn't square?

Tags: javascript, math, glsl, shader, webgl

I'm working with WebGL and I'm trying to clip away what I'm drawing to draw a circle, but currently it's drawing an ellipse instead. Here is my fragment shader:

```
void main() {
  vec4 c = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(u_center, 1)).xy, 0, 1); // center

  float r = .25; // radius

  bool withinRadius = pow(v_pos.x - c.x, 2.) + pow(v_pos.y - c.y, 2.) < r * r;

  if (!withinRadius) { discard; }

  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

I *think* the issue is that because my screen size is 1920x1200, the horizontal clip space that goes from -1.0 to +1.0 is wider than the vertical clip space that goes from -1.0 to +1.0. I think the solution might involve somehow normalizing the clip-space such that it is square, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that or what the recommended way to handle that is. How do you normally handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to scale either the x or the y component of the vector from the center of the circle to the fragment. Add a unfiorm variable or constant to the fragment shader which holds the aspect ratio (`aspect = width/height`) or the resolution of the canvas and scale the `x` component of the vector by *aspect*:

```c
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main()
{
    float aspect = u_resolution.x / u_resolution.y;

    vec4 c = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(u_center, 1)).xy, 0, 1); // center
    float r = .25; // radius

    vec2 dist_vec = (v_pos.xy - c.xy) * vec2(aspect, 1.0);
    if (dot(dist_vec, dist_vec) > r*r)
        discard;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); 
}
```

Note, I've used the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to compute the square of the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance):

```c
dot(va, vb) == va.x*vb.x + va.y*vb.y
```

Comment: Hey thanks this worked! The only thing I had to change was that I had to make `aspect` the `canvas.height / canvas.width` instead of `canvas.width / canvas.height` and then it made a circle. I'll also have to study those other changes you made with `dot` and whatnot to make sure I understand that. Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanPeschel Sorry my bad. Of course it has to be scaled by _aspect_ instead of _1/aspect_.

Comment: Ah, perfect, that change made it work with `width / height`. Cheers!

Comment: @RyanPeschel I've add an brief explanation about the Dot product.

Answer (score 0):

fragCoord - The system constant of the pixel on the screen

(https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml)

iResolution - Screen resolution that you have to transfer yourself

center - (0.5)

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

// fixe
    uv.x -= center;
    uv.x *= iResolution.x / iResolution.y;
    uv.x += center;
//

float color = length(uv-vec2(0.5));

color = smoothstep(0.46,0.47,color);
```